# Regex: republic of congo, but not democratic republic of congo

Tags: regex, perl, r

I'm struggling to write a perl-compatible regex that will be reasonably smart about distinguishing strings that refer to the republic of the congo and the democratic republic of the congo. I'll be using this expression in a program for `R`'s `grep` function which returns True if the regex matches the string and False otherwise.

The country I'm interested to identify can sometimes be written in different orders/ways. For example:

> republic of congo
>
> republic of the congo
>
> congo, republic of the
>
> congo, republic

The country I do not want to match has similar patterns:

```
democratic republic of the congo

congo, democratic republic of the

dem rep of the congo
```

What I'm looking for, I guess, is a regex that would match on rep and congo, but would fail any time there's a "dem" in the string.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: regex over a series of characters is probably too low-level for your needs.  Try a NLP library.

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW The function is used to convert country names into country codes. It matches country strings by apply one regular expression per country. I already have one regex that matches for "dem", but the function then returns the country code for the democratic republic of the congo (i.e. "DRC"). I would rather not use 2 different regex to match the republic of congo because this would require re-writing the whole function (which I have managed to keep nice and simple so far).

Comment: @agent-j I would rather not use a NLP library since the function is packaged without dependencies so far, and I'd like to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is matches your first sample strings and ignores the second

```
^(.(?<!dem))*congo(.(?<!dem))*$
```

In Perl this becomes

```
if ($subject =~ m/^(.(?<!dem))*congo(.(?<!dem))*$/m) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to check twice for `dem`. This behaves equivalently to `^(?!=.*dem)).*congo`, and doesn't check for `rep` as requested, which may come before or after `congo`.

Answer (score 3):

```
> countries <- scan(what="character")
1:     'republic of congo'
2:     'republic of the congo'
3:     'congo, republic of the'
4:     'congo, republic'
5: 'democratic republic of the congo'
6: 'congo, democratic republic of the'
7: 'dem rep of the congo'
8: 
Read 7 items
> grep("dem", countries, ignore.case=TRUE,value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
[1] "republic of congo"      "republic of the congo"  "congo, republic of the" "congo, republic"
```

Comment: Thanks! I had never looked into the invert argument. Looks useful even though it doesn't look like the best solution in my case (for reasons you couldn't see from reading my post). Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know R, but this regex will match exactly what you described, *a regex that would match on `rep` and `congo`, but would fail any time there's a `dem` in the string*

```
/^(?=.*rep)(?=.*congo)(?!.*dem)/i;
```

It also filters your sample strings as you wanted.

Comment: That's written more clearly as `/rep/i && /congo/i && !/dem/i`

Comment: @ikegami: not when it's used as an R `grep` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in **python**:

```
pattern = (?!democratic\s+)(?:republic)\s+of\s+(?:the\s+)?congo|congo,\s+republic(?:\s+of\s+the)?

// A String holding positive and negative examples mixed
string = 'republic of congo, republic of the congo, congo, republic of the, congo, republic, democratic republic of the congo, congo, democratic republic of the, dem rep of the congo'

re.findall(pattern, string) // return ['republic of congo', 'congo, republic of the', 'congo, republic', 'republic of the congo']
```